# SubnetsHaveNoServiceEndpointsConfigured error when deplying cosmosdb account

Tags: terraform, azure, mongodb

I'm trying to deploy cosmosdb account with mongodb on azure with terraform.
But 'terraform apply' times out with SubnetsHaveNoServiceEndpointsConfigured error.

> Error: creating CosmosDB Account "geo-db-2pv0c" (Resource Group
> "geo"): waiting for the CosmosDB Account "geo-db-2pv0c"
> (Resource Group "geo") to finish creating/updating:
> Code="BadRequest" Message="Database account creation failed. Operation
> Id: b2f838e87b6c, Error : {\r\n  "error": {\r\n    "code":
> "SubnetsHaveNoServiceEndpointsConfigured",\r\n    "message":
> "Subnets geo-internal-1 of virtual network
> /subscriptions/b5a3431d77a5/resourceGroups/geo/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/geo-network
> do not have ServiceEndpoints for Microsoft.AzureCosmosDB resources
> configured. Add Microsoft.AzureCosmosDB to subnet's ServiceEndpoints
> collection before trying to ACL Microsoft.AzureCosmosDB resources to
> these subnets.",\r\n    "details": []\r\n  }\r\n}\r\nActivityId:
> 95817ee8-801f-415d-ad06-06fd9af4130d,
> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0,
> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0,
> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0,
> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0,
> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0,
> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0,
> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0" │ │   with
> azurerm_cosmosdb_account.db, │   on azure_cosmosdb.tf line 9, in
> resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "db": │    9: resource
> "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "db" {

There is no info on this error and how to that endpoint to a subnet. Anyone knows how to do that?

```
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "db" {
  name                = "geofriends-db-${random_string.random-name.result}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.geofriends.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.geofriends.name
  offer_type          = "Standard"
  kind                = "MongoDB"

  enable_automatic_failover = true

  is_virtual_network_filter_enabled = true

  virtual_network_rule {
    id = azurerm_subnet.subnet-internal-1.id
  }

  capabilities {
    name = "EnableMongo"
  }

  capabilities {
    name = "MongoDBv3.4"
  }

  consistency_policy {
    consistency_level       = "BoundedStaleness"
    max_interval_in_seconds = 300
    max_staleness_prefix    = 100000
  }

  geo_location {
    prefix            = "cosmosdb-s${random_string.random-name.result}-failover"
    location          = var.failover_location
    failover_priority = 1
  }

  geo_location {
    prefix            = "cosmosdb-s${random_string.random-name.result}-main"
    location          = azurerm_resource_group.geofriends.location
    failover_priority = 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service endpoint is an Azure requirement; there's no change you could make to the CosmosDB deployment which will get around that.

Assuming you are also deploying the vnet and subnet through Terraform, then I guess you need to specify the service endpoint when you do so; see [azurerm_subnet](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/subnet#service_endpoints).

Comment: Also found "ignore_missing_vnet_service_endpoint = true" but this seems better, thanks